# Apache Spark Streaming maintain a binary search tree

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-storm

I want to understand how to do the following thing:
I want to maintain a binary search tree(BST) with spark.
I have 2 simple operations, and I get them in streaming.
That's why I thought about using Spark Streaming.

The operations are the following:
a)add a number to the BST
b)delete a number

*Lets assume that I don't have duplicate numbers.

How can I do it the right way? My main problem is that I'm not sure where should I keep the tree.
(Supposing it's size always fits in my RAM)

For me, the "Big Data" here is the number of operations, so i want to use Spark Streaming in order to handle with lots of operations which come in streams.
Again, the tree is being kept small, and will always fit in the RAM. (What if it doesn't?)

What would be the best approach?

In addition to that, I would like to do the same things using Stack data structure instead of BST.

The operations are only push and pop numbers.

Maybe Apache Storm will be better for those tasks?

Answer (score 2):

For the stack you can use redis with key as counter or timestamp when pushing, when pooping pop the latest.

Comment: well that is nice. what about if i need to do some operation on the number  before making pop operation? what can i do for that? lets assume its an easy computation.

Comment: where do i do the computation?

Comment: spark streaming, when you are analyzing each dstream, you can talk to redis in the same code. Also, can you up vote, if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

For the BST YOU could use graph x, and use it as a distributed data structure. 
Another approach could be with Akka, http://alexminnaar.com/building-a-distributed-binary-search-tree-with-akka.htm.

For the stack you may use, pair rdd with d stream, key being the the time stamp while pushing, but not sure how to pop.

Comment: can i use streaming with graph x?

Comment: Can i use some db to store my stack?